# Not able to read from JSON object after a certain level

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

Here is my problem -

```
$comment = stdClass Object
        (
            [kind] => Listing
            [data] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [modhash] => 
                    [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [kind] => t1
                                    [data] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [subreddit_id] => t5_2qh16
                                            [banned_by] => 
                                            [link_id] => t3_2qgate
                                            [likes] => 
                                            [replies] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [kind] => Listing
                                                    [data] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [modhash] => 
                                                            [children] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                                                        (

                                                               .
                                                               .
                                                               .
                                )            
                               [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [kind] => t1
                                    [data] => stdClass Object
                                          .
                                          .
                                          .
```

I'm reading the **$comment->data->children** array and I'm able to read till **$comment->data->children[0]->data->replies** perfectly .

But while I'm trying this $comment->data->children[0]->data->replies->data->children , getting error as **trying to get non-object property 'data'** .

Any help ? What I'm doing wrong ?

BTW , I've tried by converting the JSON to array also , got the error exact in same place .

Comment: You should output what `$comment->data->children[0]->data->replies->data` contains and you will probably see that it does not have a property called children. As an aside, if you are actually writing out that long of statement to access data in a JSON structure, that has serious code smell.

Comment: go forward what output is for : `var_dump($comment->data->children[0]->data->replies->data);` ?

Comment: you probably have just broken raw json string

Comment: I'm only able to get output for var_dump($comment->data->children[0]->data->replies) .